# How do BigIntegers work in detail at the fundamental level?

Tags: arrays, object, integer, data-modeling, bigint

I saw [Explain BigInt Like I'm Five](https://dev.to/preciselyalyss/explain-bigint-like-im-five-5c66), but I already understand what a BigInt *is*. I want to know how to make one though. I am trying to pick apart [BigInt.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/master/BigInteger.js) (the [v8 bigint.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/bigint.cc) is too large and I'm not familiar with C++).

For myself and perhaps others in the future, could one explain what the data model looks like for a BigInt that supports *arbitrary sized integers*? Basically, what is the object and its properties. I get that there are all the arithmetic *functions* implemented in unique ways for the BigInt, but I don't see what the *kernel* is. What is the essence of the structure of the BigInt? Perhaps [this one](https://github.com/Yaffle/BigInteger/blob/gh-pages/BigInteger.js) will be slightly easier to grok.

Comment: Knuth's *Seminumerical Algorithms* has a very extensive section on Bigint arithmetic design issues, algorithms, and computational complexity. It starts with the "grade school" algorithms, then goes into increasingly complex improvements like Karatsuba, Toom-Cook, and FFT multiplication techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BigInt` works exactly like you learned about integers in school, except the "digits" are not based on 10 symbols, they are based on 4294967296 (or 18446744073709551616, or specifically for ECMAScript 9007199254740991).

The kernel of the data model is simply a list of "digits" that are themselves fixed-size integers and a sign bit (or alternatively, the first "digit" is itself signed). Everything else would be a performance optimization.

In pseudo-code, it would look something like this:

```
record BigInt
    sign: boolean
    digits: sequence[unsigned_integer]
```

or this:

```
record BigInt
    first_digit: signed_integer
    digits: sequence[unsigned_integer]
```

Again, if you write down an integer in base-10, you write it as a sequence of digits and a sign, i.e. writing the current year, you would write: `2`, `0`, `1`, `9`, signifying (from right-to-left)

```
  9 * 10^0 =    9
+ 1 * 10^1 =   10
+ 0 * 10^2 =  000
+ 2 * 10^3 = 2000
             ====
             2019
```

Or, maybe you would write `7`, `E`, `3`, signifying (from right-to-left)

```
  3_16 * 10_16^0
+ E_16 * 10_16^1
+ 7_16 * 10_16^2
```

which is the same as

```
  3_16 * 16_10^0
+ E_16 * 16_10^1
+ 7_16 * 16_10^2
```

which is the same as

```
   3_10 * 16_10^0 =    3_10
+ 14_10 * 16_10^1 =  224_10
+  7_10 * 16_10^2 = 1792_10
                    =======
                    2019_10
```

And a `BigInt` is represented in *exactly the same way*, except the base is (much) larger.

Comment: base 10⁹ or 10¹⁹ can also be used if the main operations are input/output instead of math, since it avoids divisions by 10 when converting from/to decimal